# form validation with directives

Tags: validation, angularjs

For a long time, I've been trying create my own validation on an input with angularJS (with a directive) but nothing really works.
Even if this subject has been treated many times on stack, my directive doesn't work and I suck with AngularJS.

I want to have an error message when user writes special key in my example: "hello", "hi", "coucou".

I try it on a fiddle but just the third key sends an error message.

http://jsfiddle.net/JW43C/59/

My directive :

```
.directive('validkey',function(){
            return{
                require: "ngModel",
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
                    var forbiddenKeyword = ["hello", "hi", "coucou"];
                    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue){
                        console.log(viewValue);
                        for(var i=0;i<forbiddenKeyword.length;i++){ 
                          //  console.log(forbiddenKeyword[i]);
                        if(viewValue == forbiddenKeyword[i]){
                        ctrl.$setValidity('validkey',false);
                        console.log("error!!!!!");
                        }
                        else{                                                                                 
                        ctrl.$setValidity('validkey',true);
                        }
                      }
                     return viewValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Sorry for my english.
I start writing by my own directive (be tolerant !!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of your loop once you hit a forbiddenKeyword.

If, for example, we type in "hi" then the code sets `validkey` to false on the loop where you test against "hi".  But then on the next loop through (when you're checking against `coucou`) you'll reset the key back to true.  We want to add a `break` so that once you hit a forbiddenKeyword you jump out of the loop and stop testing other values.

I've updated your fiddle so it works now:  http://jsfiddle.net/AbKPq/

The only change was the addition of the break, so you went from this test within your while loop:

```
    if(viewValue == forbiddenKeyword[i]){
         ctrl.$setValidity('validkey',false);
         console.log("error!!!!!");
    }
```

to

```
     if(viewValue == forbiddenKeyword[i]){
          ctrl.$setValidity('validkey',false);
          console.log("error!!!!!");
          break;  //quit out of the while loop
     }
```